# Difference between poses

Tags: python, frame, ros, robotics

I'm working with the poses on Ros.

```
pose1 = tf_conversions.Frame ()
pose2 = tf_conversions.Frame ()
```

the expression `(pose1 * pose2.Inverse ())` is equivalent, if I understand correctly, to pose1-pose2 .. What does `(pose1 * pose2.Inverse ()). Inverse()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say A and B are the two poses:

[image]

To get the difference pose different between A to B we can define as

[image]

How can we define between B to A? that's what you are looking for

```
(pose1 * pose2.Inverse ()). Inverse()
```

In other words,

[image]